# Avoiding of extra indentation for additional lines of code in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

Intellij Idea gives next formatting

[image: What I have]

But I want to have indentation only once. not for every next string
(As shown below)

[image: What I want to see after auto formatting]

Please, help me to customize IDE settings.
Thanks.

Comment: The IntelliJ formatted code is way more readable than yours. I would just try to get used to it.

Comment: But in case if I have a serious amount of operators every indentation shifts code more and more. It gets more and more size. To be honest I do not like this. Thanks for your post.

Comment: Thanks to Andrii Abramov for improved formatting.

Comment: If you have so many operators and levels of indentation that it becomes hard to read, you shouldn't remove indentation and make it even harder to read. Instead, you should refactor the code and extract parts of it into functions. Using 8 spaces instead of the more traditional 2 (or 4 max) also doesn't help.